# Microsoft Exel query

Tags: excel, ms-office

I am working on a project in Microsoft Exel and I have two columns with more than 2000 records each. I want that every record of each column to be inserted within
 single ''! Can anyone help me?
any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in VBA:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    Dim colArr() As Variant, r As Long, c As Long
    colArr = ws.UsedRange.Value

    For r = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For c = 1 To ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            colArr(r, c) = "!" & colArr(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ws.UsedRange = colArr

End Sub
```

So you essentially place the entire `UsedRange` into a multi-dimensional array. Make your changes within the array then rewrite your sheet with the updated results.

You can also loop through each individual cell and make the change one at a time, but for a lot of data that is very inefficient.

---

If you are unfamiliar with VBA, read on:

> ***How do I access the VBE?***
> You can gain access to VBE by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> while you are inside your workbook.
>
> ***Okay, So I have the VBE open. Now how do I apply this SUB/Function?***
> In the left pane you will see your workbook object modules. This is called the **Project Explorer**. You will need to create a new module, which you can do by `right-clicking inside the Project Explorer > Insert > Module`:
>
> [image]
>
> Now you can paste the function to this new module and you are all set!